# More compact "if...else if" when executing same code

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a JavaScript calls structured this way:

```
if (($(this).scrollTop() == 0) && !controlsVisibility) {
   triggerControls();
}
else if (currentScroll > (previousScroll + 100) && controlsVisibility) {
   triggerControls();
};
```

While `triggerControls()` does just-in-case typecheck for `undefined`, and uses `controlsVisibility` as default arg determine what exactly it is supposed to do. I think:

- Did I made a mistake of not passing `controlsVisibility` as a function arg inside `if` clause. If value of that variable changes between I call `triggerControls()` and function's execution (microsecond?) — should I:

  1. **account for the possible change by using the global state** (*as it is now*)

     or
  2. **interfere the change by passing stable args in advance**?

     I understand that this might be determined on case-by-case basis, but I would really appreciate some tips.

If the current implementation **(1)** is OK

> I could've written both scenario checks in one `if` just by using `||` as I am executing the same function. Except for *being messy and making the code largely unreadable* why shouldn't I do just that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If value of that variable changes between I call triggerControls() and function's execution (microsecond?)

No. While your script is executing, nothing else will change that variable - JavaScript is single-threaded. Unless `triggerControls` does something asynchronous and expects the value to be the same in a future turn of the event loop, everything is fine.

> I could've written both scenario checks in one if just by using || as I am executing the same function. Except for being messy and making the code largely unreadable why shouldn't I do just that?

I don't see a reason not to do that. It's not messy to avoid repetition (but [dry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Repeat_Yourself)), and I wouln't consider it unreadable. You even might use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to shorten (and optimise) it:

```
if (controlsVisibility
      ? currentScroll > (previousScroll + 100)
      : $(this).scrollTop() == 0
) {
    triggerControls();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the statement that rolling the two conditions with an `||` operator is unreadable. With the right formatting it is very readable:

```
if (
    (($(this).scrollTop() == 0) && !controlsVisibility) ||
    (currentScroll > (previousScroll + 100) && controlsVisibility)
) {
   triggerControls();
};
```

That's clearly two conditions switched by `controlsVisibility`. I personally would prefer `controlsVisibility` to be checked first to make the fact that it's a switch clearer:

```
if (
    (controlsVisibility && currentScroll > (previousScroll + 100)) ||
    (!controlsVisibility && ($(this).scrollTop() == 0))
) {
   triggerControls();
};
```

However, you also asked if there is a more compact way to write this and there is:

```
if (controlsVisibility ?
      currentScroll > (previousScroll + 100) :
      $(this).scrollTop() == 0
) {
   triggerControls();
};
```

I'd argue that the code above is obvious and readable but not everybody likes the ternary operator.

Comment: I actually have no idea how to behave in this situation. But while I strongly felt for both answers, @Berghi 's is much more precise and professional — he catches some of my stupidity. Thank you for a detailed explanation — it's very useful.

Comment: The votes don't matter much to me. Just glad I could help. Thanks for the upvote :)